# Iterating Through Pandas Dataframe to Calculate based on Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the DataFrame below, I need to create a new column 'unit_count' which is 'unit'/'count' for each year and month.  However, because each year and month is not unique, for each entry, I only want to use the count for a given month from the B option.

```
key UID count   month   option  unit    year
0   1   100     1       A       10      2015
1   1   200     1       B       20      2015
2   1   300     2       A       30      2015
3   1   400     2       B       40      2015
```

Essentially, I need a function that does the following:

```
unit_count = df.unit / df.count
```

for value of unit, but using the only the 'count' value of option 'B' in that given 'month'.

So that the end result would look like the table below, where unit_count is dividing the number of units by the count of 'sector' 'B' for a given month.

```
key UID count   month   option  unit    year    unit_count
0   1   100     1       A       10      2015    0.05
1   1   200     1       B       20      2015    0.10
2   1   300     2       A       30      2015    0.075
3   1   400     2       B       40      2015    0.01
```

Here is the code I used to create the original DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UID':[1,1,1,1],
                'year':[2015,2015,2015,2015],
                'month':[1,1,2,2],
                'option':['A','B','A','B'],
                'unit':[10,20,30,40],
                'count':[100,200,300,400]
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can first create `NaN` where not `option` is `B` and then divide back filled `NaN` values:

*Notice: `DataFrame` has to be sorted by `year`, `month` and `option` first for last value with `B` for each group*

```
#if necessary in real data
#df.sort_values(['year','month', 'option'], inplace=True)

df['unit_count'] = df.loc[df.option=='B', 'count']
print (df)
   UID  count  month option  unit  year  unit_count
0    1    100      1      A    10  2015         NaN
1    1    200      1      B    20  2015       200.0
2    1    300      2      A    30  2015         NaN
3    1    400      2      B    40  2015       400.0

df['unit_count'] = df.unit.div(df['unit_count'].bfill())
print (df)
   UID  count  month option  unit  year  unit_count
0    1    100      1      A    10  2015       0.050
1    1    200      1      B    20  2015       0.100
2    1    300      2      A    30  2015       0.075
3    1    400      2      B    40  2015       0.100
```