# Creating a Pandas DataFrame Column with Results from the Sum of a Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941049/iterating-through-pandas-dataframe-to-calculate-based-on-conditions) question about calculating a DataFrame value from a condition, I have a more complex question about including a sum based on that condition for a given row that I am struggling with.  Here is the initial df:

```
Key UID VID count   month   option  unit    year
0   1   5   100     1       A       10      2015
1   1   5   200     1       B       20      2015
2   1   5   300     2       A       30      2015
3   1   5   400     2       B       40      2015
4   1   7   450     2       B       45      2015
5   1   5   500     3       B       50      2015
```

I am looking to iterate through this time-series DataFrame, adding a column 'unit_count' for each row that divide the value of 'unit' by the sum of 'count' in that month only where the option is 'B'. Essentially:

```
df['unit_count'] = df['unit'] / sum of df['count'] for all records containing 'option' 'B' in the same month
```

Which would append the DataFrame as follows:

```
Key UID VID count   month   option  unit    year    unit_count
0   1   5   100     1       A       10      2015    0.050
1   1   5   200     1       B       20      2015    0.100
2   1   5   300     2       A       30      2015    0.035
3   1   5   400     2       B       40      2015    0.047
4   1   7   450     2       B       45      2015    0.053
5   1   5   500     3       B       50      2015    0.100
```

The code for the example df above is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UID':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   'VID':[5,5,5,5,7,5],
                'year':[2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015],
                'month':[1,1,2,2,2,3],
                'option':['A','B','A','B','B','B'],
                'unit':[10,20,30,40,45,50],
                'count':[100,200,300,400,450,500]
                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only want to look into the same month, so you can group by the `month` column, and then in each group use `option == "B"` to subset the *count* column and take the sum, use the summed value to divide the *unit* column (A translation of your logic):

```
df['unit_count'] = df.groupby('month', group_keys=False).apply(
                      lambda g: g.unit/g['count'][g.option == "B"].sum())
df
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! I think using `.loc[]` could make it even bit nicer: `df.groupby(['year','month']).apply(lambda g: g.unit / g.loc[g.option=='B', 'count'].sum())`

Comment: @MaxU I had the same feeling but have no idea if it will be faster, but a more compact one nevertheless.

Comment: @Psidom solution works well, especially when adding the df.groupby(['year','month] that @MaxU recommends.  @MaxU's more compact solution returns two errors.  `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'` and `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`